# laptop stored in sleep mode battery died and now won't boot up windows 7

Tags: windows, laptop, sleep

I have a Windows 7 system that I accidentally stored in sleep mode and the battery went dead.  Now the PC won't start up or initiate boot sequence (on battery or plugged in).  Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Is 'anyone know what gives' your question? I don't think the capitals help.

Comment: Does it power up? Do you get anything at all on screen? Can you boot it off a CD?

Answer (score 0):

Try booting up off a Windows CD. Unless you bought the computer with Windows, you must have a spare copy of it lying around somewhere. Before booting up, put the CD into your computer. If you don't have a DVD Drive, try getting a USB with Windows on it. Just go into your boot menu, often found by pressing F12, if it isn't that key then look at the screen when it boots up, there is always a dialogue telling you which key to press. Once you are in your boot menu, just select the disk/USB on which Windows is installed on and boot from it. Once you are in Windows, you should be able to run system repair or startup repair.

I hope I helped, if you have a problem then just throw me a comment.